# Is there any encoding types in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want php URLENCODE type encoding for mysql columns.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why would any sane person want to do that on the database level?

Comment: Google results show's it can be done with a stored function, but why you'd want to do that is beyond me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't such a function embedded into MySQL, but it can be done.

[Here's a possible solution](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/7746) for your question using a [stored function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-functions.html).